# How do I get my input to a variable that i can call to use in my button?

Tags: html

I am trying to make a script that will check if a specified whole number between 1 and 20 is odd or even but i dont know how to change my input to a variable of sorts

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <h1>Input a whole number between 0 and 20</h1>
    <p1>
        <input type="number" id="myNum" name="myNum" min="0" max="20">
        <p>
            <button style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68); 
            border-color: black; 
            color:white; 
            border-radius: 5px; 
            border-width: 5px;" onclick="
            if(value %2 === 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('oddoreven').innerHTML='The number is even'
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('oddoreven').innerHTML='The number is odd'
            }">
                Check if even or odd
            </button>
        </p>
        <div id="oddoreven">
        </div>
    </p1>

    </html>
```

Comment: You're almost there, except for `value`. Where does it come from, and how can you retrieve it?

Comment: A real pro would also not use an if/else statement here but: `document.getElementById('oddoreven').textContent = 'The number is ' + !(value % 2 ) ? 'even' : 'odd';` (While you could outside of a comment simplify it more by using backticks).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <h1>Input a whole number between 0 and 20</h1>
    <p1>
        <input type="number" id="myNum" name="myNum" min="0" max="20" value="10">
        <p>
            <button style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68); 
            border-color: black; 
            color:white; 
            border-radius: 5px; 
            border-width: 5px;" onclick="
            var input = getElementById('myNum').value
            if(input %2 === 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('oddoreven').innerHTML='The number is even'
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('oddoreven').innerHTML='The number is odd'
            }">
                Check if even or odd
            </button>
        </p>
        <div id="oddoreven">
        </div>
    </p1>

    </html>
```

I'm just dumb

Comment: Save yourself some headache. Move the CSS and JS out of the HTML attributes.